# Shiny app goes into an endless loop upon quickly changing selectInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem with a shiny app where if a user quickly changes the `selectInput` the app goes into a loop bug where it shuffles back and forth the select input independently of the user. The only way to get out of the bug is to close the app.
The following example is not ideal, but it illustrates the behavior:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  p("The checkbox group controls the select input"),
  checkboxGroupInput("inCheckboxGroup", "Input checkbox",
                     c("1", "2", "3")),
  selectInput("inSelect", "Select input",
              c("1", "2", "3")),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    x <- input$inCheckboxGroup
    
    # Can use character(0) to remove all choices
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)
    
    selected <- ifelse(input$inSelect %in% x, input$inSelect, tail(x, 1))
    
    # Can also set the label and select items
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",
                      label = paste("Select input label", length(x)),
                      choices = x,
                      selected = selected
    )
  })
  
  
  output$plot <-  renderPlot({
    req(input$inSelect)
    
    dat <- as.data.frame(replicate(as.numeric(input$inSelect), rnorm(1e6)))
    
    dat %>%
      gather() %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_density(aes(x = value)) +
      facet_wrap(~key)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Select all checkboxes and change the dropdown inputs fast (<1s) to observe the problem.
The problem is somehow related to checking of current value of `input$inSelect` and using that check to update the default value of the select input. My concrete app requires this. As I understand it is a synchronization issue.

What are the possible ways to overcome it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is your use of `observe`.  By not specifiying precisely what you want to `observe`, you trigger an event whenever *any* reactive within the `observe` changes.  In your case, this is both the checkbox group and the select list.  I think you only want to trigger updates (here, at least) when the checkbox group changes, not when the selection in the selct input changes.

Therefore, the solution is easy.  Replace `observe` with `observeEvent(input$CheckBoxGroup,` .

This limits reactivity to only changes in the checkbox group.

This fixed the problem for me.

Also note that `gather` has been superseded by `pivot_longer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This does solve the loop however it changes the behavior. Select all checkboxes and then deselect them. Instead of reverting to empty dropdown it keeps the last value.

In addition `observeEvent` does not work in my real app - but perhaps this is the real issue (it should observe a reactivePoll output). Will update the the question with a better example when I construct it.

Comment: Your answer led me to investigate from another perspective - why `observeEvent` does not work in my real app leading to a solution using `observeEvent`. Thank you.